# Elasticsearch high CPU Utilization and Query Response time

Tags: elasticsearch, search, cpu-usage, heap-memory

I have been building a search feature based on Elasticsearch Service. 
The index mapping I am using is:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/cast_tag_added" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "settings": {
   "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
     "analyzer_title": {
      "tokenizer": "tokenizer_title",
      "filter": [
       "lowercase",
       "asciifolding",
       "trim"
      ]
     },
     "tokenizer": {
      "tokenizer_title": {
       "type": "edge_ngram",
       "min_gram": 2,
       "max_gram": 20,
       "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit"
       ]
      }
     }
    }
  },

  "mappings": {
   "_doc": {
    "properties": {
     "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "index": "true",
      "analyzer": "analyzer_title",
      "search_analyzer": "analyzer_search"
     },
     "id": {
      "type": "long",
      "index":"false"
     },
     "ratings": {
      "type" : "double",
      "index" : "false"
      }, 
     }   
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Sample data stored is:

```
{
    "name": "Die Hard" 
    "id": 12345
}
```

Sample Query:

```
{
    "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [{
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "die",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "boost": 2
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "die",
                                    "boost": 4
                                }
                            }
                        }
                },
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "ratings",
                    "modifier": "log1p",
                    "missing": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "explain" : true
    }
}
```

But while testing I discovered that query throughput is too less(around 24) and also the query response latency is too much(average is around 8 seconds). I added these settings to get slow log queries:

```
{
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug": "0ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace": "0ms"
}
```

This gave me response time of all the queries running.
The response time that I can see in *my-application_index_search_slowlog.log* file was very less for each query. It ranged between a few microseconds to 1 or 2 ms for all the queries. Example:

```
[2019-07-16T05:24:06,264][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [node-1] [cast_tag_added][1] took[892micros], took_millis[0], total_hits[676], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[<the search query goes here>], id[],
```

Cannot figure out why the query response latency is so high even though the response time as shown in the logs is less. Also noticed that CPU utilization spikes upto 100% a few seconds after the test starts on the elasticsearch server.

Comment: we cant help you without index mapping/sample data/involved query. Can you provide us with those pieces of information?

Comment: added the sample data, query, and indexing @PierreMallet